# What are all the possible values for SQLException.getSQLState?

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc

`SQLException.getSQLState` retrieves the `SQLState` for the `SQLException` object. What are all the possible values that can be returned by this method? Can I use the value to identify specific errors that occurred in the database (i.e. can this value tell me if it was a PK violation, or a unique constraint, or column value too large, etc.)?

Also, the `DatabaseMetaData.getSQLStateType()` method is supposed to indicate whether the `SQLSTATE` returned by `SQLException.getSQLState` is X/Open (now known as Open Group) SQL CLI or SQL99. The only possible value for this should be `DatabaseMetaData.sqlStateXOpen == 1` and `DatabaseMetaData.sqlStateSQL99 == 2` but I am getting the value `0`. Am I missing something?

Is there a way that I can determine the specific type of error that occurred in the DB using combinations from the above mentioned methods? Can I count on the values of `SQLException.getSQLState`? Are these values different from DB provider to DB provider?

Comment: [See also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1989469/521799)

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData.getSQLStateType()` is also very helpful when the `connect` attempt does already fail with an `SQLException`, so there is no `DatabaseMetaData` to query for the meaning of the exception…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official documents that include SQLStates can obviously be purchased, at a relatively high price, from ANSI and XOpen. 
But, the documentation for most databases have lists of SQLStates. Probably the most complete ( and accessible ) online listings are in the DB2 manuals. Check the [DB2 Universal Messages manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html), for instance. Oracle ( TechNet password required ) and Sybase, among others, also have online listings.

As to the second question, this is the intent of SQLState, however, the various databases have varying degrees of compliance. For example, some map multiple native error messages to the same SQLState. For generic use, one should probably concentrate on the major code ( the first two characters of SQLState, ) then determine if more specific info is available in the minor code ( beyond 000. )

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=46397

Answer (score 5):

MySQL provides some info in its reference manual in [Server Error Codes and Messages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html)

Comment: Updated link for 5.6 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-error-reference.html
5.7 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html
8.0 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html

Answer (score 4):

The X/Open (now Open Group) standards are now available free of charge (but registration required). See [Data Management: SQL Call Level Interface (CLI)](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/C451) for the SQL CLI (aka ODBC) standard, SQLSTATE codes are defined in Appendix A. And [Data Management: Structured Query Language (SQL), Version 2](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/C449) for the SQL standard, SQLSTATE codes are defined in Appendix B. As for the ISO standards, while you have to pay for the official versions, the final drafts (which are almost identical) are freely available; for SQL:2011, see page 2017 (by PDF numbering; 1194 by document page numbering) of [Final Committee Draft ISO/IEC FCD 9075-2](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1951-2000/32N1964T-text_for_ballot-FCD_9075-2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is to some degree JDBC driver-dependent. There do seem to be standard values, plus some proprietary values.

As a guide to what's possible, Spring's JDBC layer includes SQL error code and state translation. It provides a [SQLState translator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.html) which gives rather vague exception translation, as well as a [SQLErrorCode translator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html) which is much more fine-grained, using known proprietary error codes.

If you can't use Spring, then download the source code, and extract the `sql-error-codes.xml` file, which contains the mapping from codes to exception types.