# How to catch a specific exception in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

How to catch specific exceptions in [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)? Examples: primary key exception or foreign key exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQLException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html)  contains some database-specific info related to the exception. From the doc:

> Each SQLException provides several
>   kinds of information:
>
> 1) a string
>   describing the error. This is used as
>   the Java Exception message, available
>   via the method getMesage.
>
> 2) a "SQLstate"
>   string, which follows either the XOPEN
>   SQLstate conventions or the SQL 99
>   conventions. The values of the
>   SQLState string are described in the
>   appropriate spec. The DatabaseMetaData
>   method getSQLStateType can be used to
>   discover whether the driver returns
>   the XOPEN type or the SQL 99 type.
>
> 3) an
>   integer error code that is specific to
>   each vendor. Normally this will be the
>   actual error code returned by the
>   underlying database.
>
> 4) a chain to a next
>   Exception. This can be used to provide
>   additional error information.

Answer (score 29):

The best and DB-independent way to handle `SQLException` more specifically is to determine the SQL state code which can be obtained by [`SQLException#getSQLState()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState%28%29). The SQLState is a 5-char code, of which the first two are common among all DB's and the last three might differ depending on the DB and/or the specific condition. Here's an extract from the [spec](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

- 02: no data
- 07: dynamic SQL error
- 08: connection exception
- 0A: feature not supported
- 21: cardinality violation
- 22: data exception
- 23: integrity constraint violation
- 24: invalid cursor state
- 25: invalid transaction state
- 26: invalid SQL statement name
- 28: invalid authorization specification
- 2B: dependent privilege descriptors still exist
- 2C: invalid character set name
- 2D: invalid transaction termination
- 2E: invalid connection name
- 33: invalid SQL descriptor name
- 34: invalid cursor name
- 35: invalid condition number
- 3C: ambiguous cursor name
- 3D: invalid catalog name
- 3F: invalid schema name

So to determine whether the SQL Exception is caused by a constraint violation, you can just do the following in a (fictive) `SQLUtil` class:

```
public static boolean isConstraintViolation(SQLException e) {
    return e.getSQLState().startsWith("23");
}
```

Comment: I can get a verbose message from my exception informing that my new row violates certain constraint, but when I do an `e.getSQLState()` in order to customize my message I always get a `null` value. Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 5):

Brian's right, a SQLException will be thrown for just about ANY JDBC problem.  This is partially why JDBC is so annoying.  The [Spring library JDBC helpers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) provide an [exception translator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html) to look at the SQLCode, SQLState, etc., and throw the appropriate [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html).  There are many of these exception classes, and they give you a better idea of what went wrong, with names such as DataIntegrityViolationException, DataSourceLookupFailureException, PermissionDeniedDataAccessException, and others.

Comment: ^ List of great resources ^. There is so much Spring has to offer I wish I had time to review every bi of the API. 
Anyways, I also wanted to throw out there, it sounds like the question was subliminally pointing at a INSERT were the PK or FK is the same and thus cannot insert. If this is the case, you could catch a DataIntegrityViolationException, but the more appropriate handle would be to use a SQL MERGE clause instead of an INSERT. 
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Answer (score 5):

Following up on [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1989469/521799), here's a more complete, recent list of all the classes and subclasses as specified by the SQL:2011 standard. I have just recently assembled this list for the [Javadoc of jOOQ's `SQLStateSubclass`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/exception/SQLStateSubclass.java).

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Class and class description                                    | Subclass and subclass description                                  |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 00 | Successful completion                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 001 | Cursor operation conflict                                    |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 002 | Disconnect error                                             |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 003 | Null value eliminated in set function                        |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 004 | String data, right truncation                                |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 005 | Insufficient item descriptor areas                           |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 006 | Privilege not revoked                                        |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 007 | Privilege not granted                                        |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 009 | Search condition too long for information schema             |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00A | Query expression too long for information schema             |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00B | Default value too long for information schema                |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00C | Result sets returned                                         |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00D | Additional result sets returned                              |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00E | Attempt to return too many result sets                       |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 00F | Statement too long for information schema                    |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 012 | Invalid number of conditions                                 |
| 01 | Warning                                                   | 02F | Array data, right truncation                                 |
| 02 | No data                                                   | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 02 | No data                                                   | 001 | No additional result sets returned                           |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 001 | Using clause does not match dynamic parameter specifications |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 002 | Using clause does not match target specifications            |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 003 | Cursor specification cannot be executed                      |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 004 | Using clause required for dynamic parameters                 |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 005 | Prepared statement not a cursor specification                |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 006 | Restricted data type attribute violation                     |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 007 | Using clause required for result fields                      |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 008 | Invalid descriptor count                                     |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 009 | Invalid descriptor index                                     |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 00B | Data type transform function violation                       |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 00C | Undefined DATA value                                         |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 00D | Invalid DATA target                                          |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 00E | Invalid LEVEL value                                          |
| 07 | Dynamic SQL Error                                         | 00F | Invalid DATETIME_INTERVAL_CODE                               |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 001 | SQL-client unable to establish SQL-connection                |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 002 | Connection name in use                                       |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 003 | Connection does not exist                                    |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 004 | SQL-server rejected establishment of SQL-connection          |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 006 | Connection failure                                           |
| 08 | Connection exception                                      | 007 | Transaction resolution unknown                               |
| 09 | Triggered action exception                                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0A | Feature not supported                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0A | Feature not supported                                     | 001 | Multiple server transactions                                 |
| 0D | Invalid target type specification                         | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0E | Invalid schema name list specification                    | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0F | Locator exception                                         | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0F | Locator exception                                         | 001 | Invalid specification                                        |
| 0L | Invalid grantor                                           | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0M | Invalid SQL-invoked procedure reference                   | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0P | Invalid role specification                                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0S | Invalid transform group name specification                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0T | Target table disagrees with cursor specification          | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0U | Attempt to assign to non-updatable column                 | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0V | Attempt to assign to ordering column                      | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0W | Prohibited statement encountered during trigger execution | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0W | Prohibited statement encountered during trigger execution | 001 | Modify table modified by data change delta table             |
| 0Z | Diagnostics exception                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 0Z | Diagnostics exception                                     | 001 | Maximum number of stacked diagnostics areas exceeded         |
| 21 | Cardinality violation                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 001 | String data, right truncation                                |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 002 | Null value, no indicator parameter                           |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 003 | Numeric value out of range                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 004 | Null value not allowed                                       |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 005 | Error in assignment                                          |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 006 | Invalid interval format                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 007 | Invalid datetime format                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 008 | Datetime field overflow                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 009 | Invalid time zone displacement value                         |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00B | Escape character conflict                                    |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00C | Invalid use of escape character                              |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00D | Invalid escape octet                                         |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00E | Null value in array target                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00F | Zero-length character string                                 |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00G | Most specific type mismatch                                  |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00H | Sequence generator limit exceeded                            |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00P | Interval value out of range                                  |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 00Q | Multiset value overflow                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 010 | Invalid indicator parameter value                            |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 011 | Substring error                                              |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 012 | Division by zero                                             |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 013 | Invalid preceding or following size in window function       |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 014 | Invalid argument for NTILE function                          |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 015 | Interval field overflow                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 016 | Invalid argument for NTH_VALUE function                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 018 | Invalid character value for cast                             |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 019 | Invalid escape character                                     |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01B | Invalid regular expression                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01C | Null row not permitted in table                              |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01E | Invalid argument for natural logarithm                       |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01F | Invalid argument for power function                          |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01G | Invalid argument for width bucket function                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01H | Invalid row version                                          |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01S | Invalid XQuery regular expression                            |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01T | Invalid XQuery option flag                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01U | Attempt to replace a zero-length string                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01V | Invalid XQuery replacement string                            |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01W | Invalid row count in fetch first clause                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 01X | Invalid row count in result offset clause                    |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 020 | Invalid period value                                         |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 021 | Character not in repertoire                                  |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 022 | Indicator overflow                                           |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 023 | Invalid parameter value                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 024 | Unterminated C string                                        |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 025 | Invalid escape sequence                                      |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 026 | String data, length mismatch                                 |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 027 | Trim error                                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 029 | Noncharacter in UCS string                                   |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 02D | Null value substituted for mutator subject parameter         |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 02E | Array element error                                          |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 02F | Array data, right truncation                                 |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 02G | Invalid repeat argument in sample clause                     |
| 22 | Data exception                                            | 02H | Invalid sample size                                          |
| 23 | Integrity constraint violation                            | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 23 | Integrity constraint violation                            | 001 | Restrict violation                                           |
| 24 | Invalid cursor state                                      | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 001 | Active SQL-transaction                                       |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 002 | Branch transaction already active                            |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 003 | Inappropriate access mode for branch transaction             |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 004 | Inappropriate isolation level for branch transaction         |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 005 | No active SQL-transaction for branch transaction             |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 006 | Read-only SQL-transaction                                    |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 007 | Schema and data statement mixing not supported               |
| 25 | Invalid transaction state                                 | 008 | Held cursor requires same isolation level                    |
| 26 | Invalid SQL statement name                                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 27 | Triggered data change violation                           | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 27 | Triggered data change violation                           | 001 | Modify table modified by data change delta table             |
| 28 | Invalid authorization specification                       | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2B | Dependent privilege descriptors still exist               | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2C | Invalid character set name                                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2C | Invalid character set name                                | 001 | Cannot drop SQL-session default character set                |
| 2D | Invalid transaction termination                           | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2E | Invalid connection name                                   | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2F | SQL routine exception                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 2F | SQL routine exception                                     | 002 | Modifying SQL-data not permitted                             |
| 2F | SQL routine exception                                     | 003 | Prohibited SQL-statement attempted                           |
| 2F | SQL routine exception                                     | 004 | Reading SQL-data not permitted                               |
| 2F | SQL routine exception                                     | 005 | Function executed no return statement                        |
| 2H | Invalid collation name                                    | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 30 | Invalid SQL statement identifier                          | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 33 | Invalid SQL descriptor name                               | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 34 | Invalid cursor name                                       | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 35 | Invalid condition number                                  | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 36 | Cursor sensitivity exception                              | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 36 | Cursor sensitivity exception                              | 001 | request rejected                                             |
| 36 | Cursor sensitivity exception                              | 002 | request failed                                               |
| 38 | External routine exception                                | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 38 | External routine exception                                | 001 | Containing SQL not permitted                                 |
| 38 | External routine exception                                | 002 | Modifying SQL-data not permitted                             |
| 38 | External routine exception                                | 003 | Prohibited SQL-statement attempted                           |
| 38 | External routine exception                                | 004 | Reading SQL-data not permitted                               |
| 39 | External routine invocation exception                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 39 | External routine invocation exception                     | 004 | Null value not allowed                                       |
| 3B | Savepoint exception                                       | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 3B | Savepoint exception                                       | 001 | Invalid specification                                        |
| 3B | Savepoint exception                                       | 002 | Too many                                                     |
| 3C | Ambiguous cursor name                                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 3D | Invalid catalog name                                      | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 3F | Invalid schema name                                       | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 40 | Transaction rollback                                      | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 40 | Transaction rollback                                      | 001 | Serialization failure                                        |
| 40 | Transaction rollback                                      | 002 | Integrity constraint violation                               |
| 40 | Transaction rollback                                      | 003 | Statement completion unknown                                 |
| 40 | Transaction rollback                                      | 004 | Triggered action exception                                   |
| 42 | Syntax error or access rule violation                     | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| 44 | With check option violation                               | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
| HZ | Remote database access                                    | 000 | No subclass                                                  |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `getErrorCode()` method to handle exceptions correctly, especially useful when you work with stored procedures or functions and you have got your own custom error codes.

It may be helpful for someone having a similar context.

Answer (score 0):

In the catch clause you can be more specific to handle that `Exception`.

```
try {

// Your code here

} catch(SQLException ex){
    if(ex instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
          // Handle Here
    }
}
```

Comment: It is usually better to use an extra specific catch-clause, instead of using if.

Comment: Of course I added the sugar, you finish up the with adding tea! But I prefer this way because before going inside the `if` I usually use the general exception and for me it is more maintainable but the choice is always dependent on developer.