# how to find duplicate value is inserting into sqllite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am doing like these

```
public void insertNewCustomere(NewCustomer ncust) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("cname", ncust.cName);
        values.put("date", ncust.date);
        values.put("caddress", ncust.cAddress);
        mdb.insert(CREATE_NEWCUSTOMER, null, values);
        if( mdb.insert(CREATE_NEWCUSTOMER, null, values)==-1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Name already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
            ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, " \n Details Submited Successfully.Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
            ContentValues values2= new ContentValues();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
Cursor mCursor = null;
            mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {KEY_NAME},KEY_NAME+" = ?",
                     new String[] {uName},null, null, null);

            if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set a unique constraint on this field if it's a short field and catch the exception of violating a unique constraint.
That will save you lots of pain and time.

---

Cheers

Comment: i am using primary key for name column.how to find same name enter second time.

Comment: Catch the primary key violation exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988570/how-to-catch-a-specific-exceptions-in-jdbc --  integrity constraint violation