# Java Mysql Integrity Constraint Violation Exception

Tags: mysql, swing, exception, constraints, unique-constraint

My Swing applications throws few exceptions. I tried to catch Integrity Constraint Violation Exception and display message "Duplicate ID". But when that happened, without catching it here: catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) it goes to catch (SQLException ex). What I want to do is, catch Integrity Violation exception and display user friendly message instead of technical message comes from ex.getMessage(). How do I do this?

```
              ShippmentTransfer shipTrns = new ShippmentTransfer(shipID, GIN, issueDate, ToStore, itemName, Qty, Driver, Vehicle);
                    int res = ShipmentTansController.addShipGIN(shipTrns);
                    if (res > 0) {
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added");
                          resetAll();
                    }
              } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate ID");

              } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
              } 
              catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.gets);
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to catch a specific SQLException, you need to compare against SQL state using `getSQLState()` method. Ex: SQL State 23 for Data Integrity violation.

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
    if (ex.getSQLState().startsWith("23")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate");
    } 
}
```

[Found from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988570/how-to-catch-a-specific-exceptions-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 1):

you can not use

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException  directly.
```

Because no exception available in java with that name.

try this

```
try {

}
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
    .....
}
```

and then get the error code using ex.Then compare it

Comment: Thnx for your response. Then how do I catch the Integrity Constraint Violation Exception? Do you have any idea?

Comment: try to get the name of exception using ex.Then compare

Comment: try to debug ex when raised the exception.What it contains when IntegrityVoilationException raises and other raised.

Comment: Sure. I ll try in that way.

Comment: Finally managed to sort it out. I used method getSQLState() produces specific error code. Ex. 23 for Data Integrity violation. if(ex.getSQLState().startsWith("23")){ Anyway I appreciate your effort to help me.

Comment: @user2033382 if you got the solution with my answer please accept this as answer

Comment: I tried using your code. catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) But such a thing not exists. When I apply that code, it says can not find symbol. Which means can not use DataIntegrityViolationException inside catch block. I got solution from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988570/how-to-catch-a-specific-exceptions-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

For those checking later,
you might either choose to check instance type as:

```
try {
...
} catch (Exception e) {

    if (e instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
          // duplicate record or alike problem
    }
}
```