# Checking record with a foreign key exists

Tags: scala, slick

Should i check the existence of foreign key with an sql request or should I just try to insert and catch if it fails?

I can check if the key i'm referencing exists or not.

My question is more of a theoretical: Catching an exception vs. querying db one more time for every insert.

For example say you have two tables, Cats and Humans. Cats has a foreign key referencing Human. Before I try to insert a Cat should I check if a human with given cat's owner column exists or should I try to insert blindly and catch if it fails.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to provide more details about the problem you're facing, i.e.: is it an external database you've got no control over that you're looking to check for the foreign key? how does the database schema/entity model looks like? why would it fail when you're trying to insert a new record (fk usually prevents updating/deleting existing records, unless you're trying to insert with non existent dependency)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple answer and it really depends on your application requirements.

Though as a general rule of thumb you should avoid counting on exception being thrown as a part of the normal application flow and there are a couple of problems with using exceptions.

- Firstly when receiving SQL Exception you'd need to identify the source of exception and this can be complex and database specific (see here for details: [How to catch a specific exception in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988570/how-to-catch-a-specific-exceptions-in-jdbc))
- Secondly even when you manage to restrict your exception code to the **referential integrity** ones you'll still face the task of identification of the source of the problem should the `Cat` reference both a `Human` and its favourite `Food`.
- In addition, even when you managed to identify that the source of error is a missing referential integrity there can a few reasons for it (so rather than simply inserting the new row you'd require some additional investigation). Imagine that you want to insert a cat for the *'Dorothy Smith'*, while you're trying to do so Dorothy got married (likely the cat was a wedding present from the spiteful mother-in-law ;) and changed her name to *'Dorothy Griffith'*. So now when you try to insert the cat, you'll duplicate Dorothy in your database, if you just blindly insert a new record.
- Moreover due to the reason described above, it makes sense to use artificially created id's for foreign key (rather than a set of fields which uniquely identifies the user). In such case you'd need to obtain this internal id first (there are a couple of ways to work around it if you don't want you application to know about the identifiers, with stored procedures and using ORM framework such as Hibernate being the most common one).

Having said that, I can still imagine a situations where handling the exceptions will have its benefits, mostly when you need to address a particular performance requirement. The example of such situation can be a trading system where you've got currencies and a fast ticking exchange rates for them. Since it happens so rarely that the new currency is introduced it can be treated as a kind of an exceptional situation and it doesn't make sense to check whether it exists (though in a correctly designed system this will only save you from calling the hashing function for checking whether the currency exists as surely you cache all the currencies internally, which in fact might be faster than wrapping the db call with `try ... catch ...` block).

So in summary try not use the exceptions, but work around the issue with correctly defining your application logic and fall back to using exceptions if you really have to.

Comment: I didn't understand why would Dorothy be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

This paragraph is present in the question

**i.e For example say you have two tables, Cats and Humans. Cats has a foreign key referencing Human. Before I try to insert a Cat should I check if a human with given cat's owner column exists or should I try to insert blindly and catch if it fails.**

Here it is mentioned that CAT has a foreign key referencing HUMAN.

So there is no need of checking whether HUMAN have a key(record for) which you are inserting as foreign key in CAT table.

Because DB throws

**integrity constraint (FK_T_NAME) violated - parent key not found exception**

Suppose if you are using Oracle DB then it throws following exception

**ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found**

So whenever you get this exception it means the value you are inserting as foreign key in CAT table is not present in HUMAN table.

Same I tested using JDBC it gives following error

Caused by: **java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_T_NAME) violated - parent key not found