# Catch duplicate key insert exception

Tags: java, mysql, try-catch

I have a table with a unique primary key column called `id`. Sometimes when I perform an `INSERT` query I get an error because the `id` value is already used.

Can I catch this specific error with `try` and `catch`?

Comment: What does not work when you use a try/catch?

Comment: I did, but it's not catching it.

Comment: Could you show that code?

Comment: do you want to catch specially primary key exist error?

Comment: In addition to what @sp00m asked, which exception class did you put in your catch block?

Comment: You shouldn't be catching it as you should really only catch `Exceptions` in Java

Comment: I mean `Error` class in Java - you shouldn't catch it...

Comment: @Lucas what other option is there, though?

Comment: you can check primary key exist or not before insert and give a error

Comment: I doing some task simultaneously. What if the PK does not exist when I checking it but on INSERT it exists?

Comment: Which error is thrown? Could you please provide the try/catch you used and the stacktrace?

Comment: read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988570/how-to-catch-a-specific-exceptions-in-jdbc

Comment: @fastsnail sure, but wouldn't that be less efficient to have to dig through the table each time you want to insert?

Comment: Can you show me INSERT statement? try use SQLException?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like mysql is throwing 1062 error code for duplicate primary key. You can check the error code for your sql exception :

```
public static final int MYSQL_DUPLICATE_PK = 1062;

try{
    //code that throws sql exception
} catch(SQLException e){
    if(e.getErrorCode() == MYSQL_DUPLICATE_PK ){
        //duplicate primary key 
    }
}
```

Notice that this approach is not cross database vendor, because different vendors might have different error codes for duplicate PK.

Comment: I thought `SqlException` was the class but wasn't sure. Great idea on checking for specific error code - I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: For completeness - Under Oracle I believe the error code returned is `1` [see here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00001_unique_constraint_violated.htm).