# check if org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException is serialization failure

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, jooq

I get a org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException in Java with a message

> ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
>     Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
>     Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.

I want to check the error code for the data access exception, which is a Postgres database behind the scene. For example,  serialization failure exception error code is [40001](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

How can i check the error code for the org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException?

My motive is to retry transaction if it's serialization failure.

Comment: You can try and `.getCause()`; normally the cause is the underlying exception and with some luck, this will be your PostgreSQL specific exception. Note however that this makes your code non portable...

Comment: @fge: The SQL states aren't PostgreSQL specific, [they're specified in the SQL standard...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34658230/521799)

Comment: @LukasEder aah, nice, I wasn't aware of that...

Comment: Yes. In fact, people often confuse the SQL standard SQL states ([`SQLException#getSQLState()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState--)) with the vendor specific error codes ([`SQLException#getErrorCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode--))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jOOQ 3.8, [`SQLStateClass`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/exception/SQLStateClass.java) and [`SQLStateSubclass`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/exception/SQLStateSubclass.java) were introduced ([#4904](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4904)) to give you type safe access to the SQL standard SQL state values.

```
catch (DataAccessException e) {
    System.out.println(e.sqlStateClass());
    System.out.println(e.sqlStateSubclass());

    if (SQLStateSubclass.C40001_SERIALIZATION_FAILURE == e.sqlStateSubclass()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Prior to jOOQ 3.8, you can access the underlying `SQLException` in order to access these SQL state values:

```
catch (DataAccessException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof SQLException &&
       ("40001".equals(((SQLException) e.getCause()).getSQLState()))) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lucas. I did check for instanceof SQlException. It worked.