# Is there a reliable (proper?) way for code to know if a SQLException was due to a connection error?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I know that an exception to due a connection error usually has a string with "Connection closed" or something similar, but that's not really a good way to know if it was a connection problem that cause the sql error instead of a data integrity issue.

For example, what if the code is executing multiple statements and the connection dies between statement 1 and 2? How cna I know I know it's a connection issue and not a problem with the sttement?

EXAMPLE:

```
try
{
    conn.createStatement().execute( sql );

    //Imagine it dies here

    conn.createStatement().execute( sql2 );
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    //Something like one of these
    if ( e.getErrorCode() === SQLException.CONNECTION_ERROR ) {}
    if ( e instance of SQLCOonnectionException ) {}
}
```

Comment: @StevenB this is not true there are lots of sql statements you can try to execute that can result in a SQLException, like removing foreign keys for one

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something which is explained here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html

Oracle has also an given example how you can retrieve a lot of  information like error code, SQLstate etc. from an SQLException.

Comment: there is also one more link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/appdev.111/b31228/appd.htm which contains oracle error codes. If you can get the error code then you will be able to match and identify the cause. These are some connection related codes.

08000 connection exception
08001 SQL client unable to establish SQL connection
08002 connection name in use
08003 connection does not exist  
08004 SQL server rejected SQL connection
08006  connection failure

Comment: Thank you. I see in their example they state that yu use the string returned from `getSQLState()` but in the second link you provided, those are `int`s. Would those be exactly what's returned from the method? And what about this: `"Indicates whether the SQLSTATE returned by SQLException.getSQLState is X/Open (now known as Open Group) SQL CLI or SQL:2003"` Does that mean the codes might be different?

Comment: Yes, they are ints but you have to cast them to String because e.getSQLState() will return string. 
_if(e.getSQLState().equals("08003"))
   {
    //What to do
   }_

The second link I shared I think it contains information about Oracle codes only. You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399574/what-are-all-the-possible-values-for-sqlexception-getsqlstate to read more about sql states.

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't see to work for me. If I open a connection, close it and then try to create a statement, I get a `SQLException` but `getSQLState()` returns `null`!

Comment: I tried the same scenario and it worked.
_'Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
  String query="Select * from some_table";
  stmt.execute(query);
  stmt.close();
  connection.close();
  stmt.execute(query);
}
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
   System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
   if(e.getSQLState().equals("08003"))
   {
    System.out.println("connection does not exist");
   }
  }'

'Output:
17009
08003
connection does not exist'_

Comment: I get: `null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` And it's at the line where you say `e.getSQLState().equals( "08003" )`

Comment: Maybe this is the reason: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64684/keyprog5.htm `"For exceptions from the Oracle JDBC drivers:

getSQLState() returns null (no meaningful information)."`